Multisite non sxa Sitecore site, some page item in other site are coming via different site url followed by content tree path
I have a Sitecore 8 multisite solution. There are sites as
Sitecore
 content
  site A
   |>home
    |>page items
  :
  :
  site B
   |>home
     |>parent page item 
       |>page item XYZ

Now, In CD I am able to access this xyz item as
https://{siteB-url}/parent page item/ page item XYZ

And this is expected, the problem is that if I hit
https://{siteA-url}/Sitecore/content/site B/parent page item/ page item XYZ

The same page is appeared.
I can see the robots.txt is same for site A and site B
User-agent: *
Disallow: /App_Browsers/
Disallow: /App_config/
Disallow: /App_Data/
Disallow: /temp/
Disallow: /sitecore


Sitemap: sitemap_siteA.xml
Sitemap: sitemap_siteB.xml

Also showconfig looks as below which I think is fine
    <site name="siteA" hostName="siteA.local" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/siteA" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" dictionaryDomain="MYSITES" disableClientData="false" requireLogin="true" loginPage="/login" enableTracking="false" patch:source="Sitecore.Forms.config" formsRoot="{B09BD3C7-D758-49B7-92D0-B6B0050E9EBA}"/>  

    <site name="siteB" hostName="siteB.local" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/siteB" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" dictionaryDomain="MYSITES" disableClientData="false" requireLogin="false" loginPage="/login" enableTracking="false" patch:source="mysites.Sites.config"/>        

Any suggestions to solve these or where and what shall I be looking for?
PS: the monsido crawler is indexing this URL which is unwanted
https://{siteA-url}/Sitecore/content/site B/parent page item/ page item XYZ
The google search shows the page from https://{siteB-url}/parent page item/ page item XYZ(which is ok.)

You can check for following settings that is used for resolving cross-site links on the website.

Rendering.SiteResolving – enables site resolving, so that cross-site links can be rendered with the correct hostname, language, and virtual folder.

Rendering.SiteResolvingMatchCurrentSite - an item location is taken into consideration when a cross-site link is built. All items under a certain site root will be resolved in the context of that root.

Rendering.SiteResolvingMatchCurrentLanguage – if set to "true", a context language is taken into consideration when a cross-site link is built.`


You can check all these are set to true to resolve cross-site links properly. These setting will be there on Web.config file in case the version is less than 8.0, whereas for version greater than 8.0 these settings reside on App_Config\Sitecore.config file.
Hope this helps!!!

Thanks, I checked those settings in App_Config\Sitecore.config and all these are set to be true
